# In Vim, how to delete the suffix of a word?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

In vim, in normal mode, if the cursor is in a word, not the last letter, `de` deletes the suffix of the word, from the position of the cursor.  If the cursor is on the last letter, `x` does it too, while `de` would jump to the end of the next word.

What command would you use that would work in both cases, last letter or not?

The purpose is to include the command in a macro.

Comment: That behavior depends not on length of a word, but on position of the cursor.  If the cursor is at the last character of a word, `e` motion would also jump to the end of the next word.

Comment: That's right, thanks again.  The question is corrected.

Comment: Answered already, but `cw` may also be useful to you.  It does what you describe, but also jumps you into edit mode.

Comment: Thanks @ElYobo, `cw` is easier to remember!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `vwged` instead of `de`, and define a mapping like the following, if you
like it.

```
:nnoremap <leader>de vwged
```

It seems to do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try `d/\>` which translates to delete upto next end word boundary.

Answer (score 1):

If your word separator is space, `dt<space>` will work. `t` will match all characters until the specified character.

Comment: Some helpful comment: dw - deletes what they call "small" word. Like in "settings.config" if you are on "s", `dw` would delete everything before `.` to delete the whole string, use `dW` (delete "big" word)

Comment: To generalize this solution: `dtC`, where `C` is the character next to the last character of the word to delete.

Comment: but what if your word is followed by a comma or a semicolon (or any other character that isn't a word?)?  You need a way to jump to the next word boundary

Comment: @Nathan Yes, to use this solution you need to seek the character next to the end of the word, and type it after `dt` (for example, `dt;`).  To get rid of the need to do it, try the mapping in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
:s/\w\+//
```

This will substitute at the beginning of the line.
To make it substitute at the position of the cursor you have to add some lines to your vimrc. Follow the instructions here

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Repeating_a_substitute_from_current_cursor_position