# How can replace all the letters between the cursor and end of the word boundary with Vim?

Tags: vim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Vim: How do I delete a word and go into insert mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379198/in-vim-how-do-i-delete-a-word-and-go-into-insert-mode)

Whilst editing in Vim I regularly end up yanking lines of DB schema and pasting them back in. I need to then replace the field names. So for example I have:

```
`field_name` YEAR(4) NOT NULL,
```

If I have the cursor on the `f` of `field_name` how can I then replace all the letters between there and the word boundary?

I have [found that you can use `de`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086848/in-vim-how-to-delete-the-suffix-of-a-word) to delete everything between there and the word boundary, but it doesn't drop into insert mode after the delete so its not truly a replacement operation.

I want something that will operate as though you ran `se` (doesn't work - I tried).

Do you know the keystrokes to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cw` should do the job - will delete and drop you into insert mode.

Answer (score 1):

I think the command is: `ce`

Meaning: Change until End of word and sets mode to insert data.

Answer (score 1):

Try `ciw` in command mode, will remove the word and put you in insert mode.

Answer (score 1):

In your case both will work. The difference between `ce` and `cw` is, that `ce` looks for the end of the next word. 
So in case that you cursor is on a blank before `field_name`, `ce` would delete the blank and `fild_name` while `cw` would only delete the blank space.